# How to display a String array and an Integer array in one ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, alignment, counter

I have recently started making an Android app that requires a list of 20 names and counters for each individual name, both displayed on the screen. Every time someone taps a name, the counter for that name increases by one. This means that the name and the counter need to be 'connected' in some way.

I started off by creating a basic list of names using a `ListView`. This is my code:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity { 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] NAMES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, NAMES));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) //Shows toast with name
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the list_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Now I'm looking for a way to display the counters in the list. The most user friendly one in my opinion would be a list in which the names are displayed on the left (which is currently the case) and their counters on the right (in one line with the names; alignment in a list is not my problem).

However, since I'm just a beginner in Android, I'm not sure how to pull this off. My first problem is that I don't know how to somehow merge my list of 20 names with a list of 20 integers and make these integers specific for each name. My second issue is how to display all this on the screen.

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Thanks, I think this will help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize your row data(name + counter) in a simple `Model` class:

```
class Model {
    String name;
    int counter;

    Model(String name, int counter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return name;
    } 
}
```

Then construct a row layout to show the name and counter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally bind the `Model` data to the row layout:

```
public class ModelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

        private ArrayList<Model> data;

        public ModelAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Model> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            data = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // let the adapter bind the name to the list
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // find the counter TextView so we can update it's value
            TextView counterTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            //get the data from the list for this row.
            Model obj = data.get(position);
            //set the counter value for this row
            counterTv.setText(String.valueOf(obj.counter));
            return v;
        }       

    }
```

To use your new adapter:

```
   //...
    String[] NAMES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_array);
    // construct the list of model object for your rows:
    ArrayList<Model> items = new ArrayList<Model>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        items.add(new Model(NAMES[i], 0));// I guess the counter starts at 0
    }
    mAdapter = new ModelAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.name, items);
    setListAdapter();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);      

//...
```

The `ListActivity` already has the `OnItemClickListener` implemented, is the `onListItemClick` method:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Model clickedRowData = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        clickedRowData.counter++;
                        // notify the adapter that something was updated
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to set up a custom listview item with the name and integer organized how ever you want. Then in your onItemSelect listener simply increment that integer and call notifyDataSetChanged. the blog post provided by Samir seems like a very good jumping off point for setting up your custom listview items.